# HTACCESS Conditions and/or Rewrites are NOT working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Problem with my root .htaccess file.

**That's my .htaccess file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# START
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]

# PAGE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !category
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

# POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !category
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&post=$2 [QSA,L]

# CATEGORY
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} category
RewriteRule ^category$ category.php [QSA,L]

# SINGLE CATEGORY
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ category.php?category=$1 [QSA,L]

# XML SITEMAP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When I try to go to

> www.pixel-factory.at/category

as a result I get a empty "page". This means it goes to

> www.pixel-factory.at/index.php?page=category

(which don't exists) instead of going to

> www.pixel-factory.at/category.php

Please someone help, can't get it done. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor your conditions to shorter your code, remove `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} category` condition everywhere and reorder your rules to keep generic rules in the end:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# XML SITEMAP
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]

# skip all rules from existing files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# CATEGORY
RewriteRule ^category/?$ category.php [NC,L]

# SINGLE CATEGORY
RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/?$ category.php?category=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

# search term
RewriteRule ^search/([\w-]+)/?$ search.php?search=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

# PAGE
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

# POST
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&post=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try! What this `(\w+)` stands for?

Comment: `\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: But I also need the hyphen? And why do I have to use the NC flag on the Category Rewrites?

Comment: Now I have the problem that my site is loading really slow and that anything is working anymore.

Comment: Nothing is working with this. When I go to `/category` I get endless loading page.

Comment: All these URLs are working fine on my Apache with above rules. Where is this htaccess located and what is `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: I think I got it done, could you please tell me how I can handle a search term? `/search/{search-term}` should adress `/search.php?search={search-term}` Thank you!

Comment: Added `search` rule and you can add similar rule on this pattern.